# using `at' to execute bash script

Tags: linux, bash, batch-processing

I made a bash script that invoke jvm to execute a jar prog. The script works well. I want to use the prog `at' to execute my bash script at some time, but the script only works partly:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch hello.world
while read line
do
    touch another.hello.world
    name=$line
...
done < "/users/me/readin.txt"
```

The command I used:

```
$ at -f myscript.bash now
```

Only *hello.world* file was generated, but no *another.hello.world*. So, there must be something wrong in my script or the command usage. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong? `at` scripts have no stdin, so of course nothing inside the `while read` loop is run; there's no input for it to iterate over unless you redirect from a file -- and if you're redirecting the loop's input, the example you gave here doesn't show it.

Comment: It works for me.  What is the content of `readin.txt`?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma merely a number of lines of text, splitted by \t. this script had ever worked on another linux box, but now it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it possible that either or both the input and script files were copied to/from a windows box?  *nix uses "\n" as a line delimiter whereas windows uses "\r\n".  Confusion and unexplained failures ensue when the two are mixed.  Using dos2unix or unix2dos utilities might sort your files out.

Comment: Try changing `while read line` to `while read -d $'\t' line`, or `< "/users/me/readin.txt"` to `< <( tr '\t' '\n' < "/users/me/readin.txt" )`

Comment: Can you post the content of `/users/me/readin.txt` file ?

Answer (score 0):

The only probability of `another.hello.world` file not being created is iteration of while loop is not happening at least once.

So probably input file `/users/me/readin.txt` is blank.

I suggest you to execute code with `set -x` option, you will find the reason. It will display the trace of what is being execute.

```
#!/bin/bash

touch hello.world
set -x
while read line
do
    touch another.hello.world
    name=$line
...
done < "/users/me/readin.txt"
set +x
```